# Starting rqworker using supervisor causes spawn error

Tags: django, supervisord, python-rq, django-rq

Trying to start rqworker as stated in its [README](https://github.com/ui/django-rq) using this command:

```
python manage.py rqworker default
```

For some reason it gives `ERROR (spawn error)` and status shows `FATAL Exited too quickly (process log may have details)`. Logs has no any information for error (`exit status 1; not expected`).

My supervisor configuration:

```
[program:rqworker]
user=ubuntu
directory=/var/www/project/
command=/var/www/project/venv/bin/python manage.py rqworker default > /var/log/project/rq.log
stopsignal=TERM
autorestart=true
autostart=true
numprocs=1
```

Running command directly from `ubuntu` user works as expected.

Comment: Did you see the supervisor log?

Comment: @gushitong it only shows `exit status 1; not expected`, no any error details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a PR on how to set this up on Ubuntu which may help you.

https://github.com/W7PEA/django-rq/blob/4afc19ab9866882c1809f89f84066856c94d75c6/README.rst

Deploying on Ubuntu
Create an rqworker service that runs the high, default, and low queues.

`sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/rqworker.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Django-RQ Worker
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=<<path_to_your_project_folder>>
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/<<your_virtualenv>>/bin/python \
    <<path_to_your_project_folder>>/manage.py \
    rqworker high default low

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable and start the sevice

`sudo systemctl enbable rqworker`
`sudo systemctl start rqworker`